# Null Pointer Exception with the actionBar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, swipe

I have implemented `swipe` view but I am getting a `Null Poitner Exception` and the `logcat` says:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.app.ActionBar$Tab android.app.ActionBar.newTab()' on a
>   null object reference at
>   com.example.android.mainactivityiit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)

I have been through numerous answers for the same question but none solved my issue. I changed the getActionBar to getSupportActionBar but still the error stays. Pleaase help me at the earliest.
here is my code:(Edited latest code)

```
    package com.example.android.mainactivityiit;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

this is tabspageadapter:

```
package com.example.android.mainactivityiit;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

I have implemented this activity using intent so the manifest file is for the other activity from which I am calling the swipe view activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.mainactivityiit" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityiit"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes??? What more should be included in the question???

Comment: At which particular line you are getting exception?

Comment: actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
     .setTabListener(this));
On this line in the code

Comment: Hey may I know why I have got so many downvotes to this question !

Comment: i tried your code it's work perfectly in my demo.

Comment: Can you please assist me. Actually I am just trying to implement swipe view on a sliding menu view. I have implemented both but at a time only one activity shows up. So how to call one fragment of an activity from other fragment of a different activity. Also do let me know about the changes so that the code works perfectly. As I mentioned in the comment below I commented the error lines and now the app is atleast starting but the tabs dont show up but I am able to swipe change the screen.

Comment: place your latest code in your question then i will help you.

Comment: and also place your TabsPagerAdapter class code...

Comment: please look for the updated codes and tabs pager java code

Comment: your code is perfect

Comment: give me your AndroidManifest.xml file code....

Comment: Have a look at the manifest of the calling activity.

Comment: I have been messing around with this since the morning and no leads till now, no answers yet except the downvotes, where are the stackoverflow minds. Please help. its really frustrating.

Comment: yr everything is ok then what happen with your demo..

Comment: comment  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivityiit"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> this activity and try to run

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
 actionBar = getActionBar();
```

to

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

**UPDATE :**

you have to import android.support.v7.app.actionBar not android.app.actionBar.

hope this will helps you.

Comment: He already wrote in his question that this wont change anything in his case.

Comment: @Nidhoegger see the code completely he changed only in some places.

Comment: Changing this says required "android.app.actionBar" found "android.support.v7.app.actionBar" And shows error and when I change the import statement it shows hell lot of errors.

Comment: @Nag: The only `getActionBar` or `getSupportActionBar` I see is in `line 28`. See OP: ` I changed the getActionBar to getSupportActionBar but still the error stays`

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal you have to import android.support.v7.app.actionBar not android.app.actionBar.

Comment: See edited comment. I did that but then it turns out to be a disaster and shows so many errors.

Comment: @Nidhoegger see the import statement as well, he has to change that.

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal what is that errors or update your code.

Comment: @Nag: Then state that in your answer. Atm you answer is wrong.

Comment: When I change the import statement it shows 4 or 5 errors. like for the overide methods at last it says method cannot overide method from its superclass and class mainactivity can either be declared as abstract or implement abstract method.

Comment: Please atleast reply and do let me know if any other information is needed . Don't know y the question is downvoted.

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal delete the last three tab related methods and implement once again bcoz those are android.app.actionbar related methods.

Comment: I commented the last three methods then it shows one last error which says "class mainactivity can either be declared as abstract or implement abstract method onTabselected(tab, fragmenttransaction) in tablistener"

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal why you written two onTabselected(-,-) methods?

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal Just remove that method one onTabselected(-,-) is enough for your requirement.

Comment: Removing those methods generates an error same as what in my last comment.

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal If you remove that methods how it will show error there?

Comment: Its showing because I think my activity implements tablistener and we ought to include that in our method.I dont know but I am telling what it is showing.

Comment: @AnamikaAgrwal you have to remove all the tab and actionbar related methods and implement once again.

Comment: ok now what I tried myself is that I removed the lines where the Nullpointerexception was showing i.e. for (String tab_name : tabs) {
  // actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
  //   .setTabListener(this));
 Now the app runs but we dont see any tabs and when I swipe it swipes but stops in the middle and the app stops.

Comment: ok Now that I commented this line too actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
the runs fine but the tabs don't show up. Can anyone suggest me edits further to give this question a closure.

Comment: Is there anyone available who can still answer this.